# Give an example of a linear operator without cyclic vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Give an example of a linear operator without cyclic vectors.

I wondered if there are such linear operators without cyclic vectors, but so far I have not been able to come up with an example

Comment: How about the identity operator?